# Interval tree implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So I'm trying to implement a simple interval tree but i having trouble getting started because I'm a little confused about the recursion.

Assume that you are given an expression tree that contains only integer constants and the binary operators `’-’, ’+’, ’*’` and `’/’`. Here’s an example:

```
+
/ \
2 *
/ \
4 55
```

**The following is the expression tree node definition:**

```
public class ETNode {

String data; 

// either integer constant or binary operator

ETNode left, right;

...}
```

(a) Complete the following method to evaluate an expression given a reference to the root of its expression
tree. You may implement helper methods if you wish.

// Evaluates an expression tree given its root, returns 0 if tree is empty
public static double evaluate(ETNode root) {

(Things to know: The `Integer.parseInt(String)` method returns the int value represented by the string parameter. The `Character.isDigit(char)` method returns true if the char parameter is a digit,false otherwise.)

Comment: What have you done so far? What exactly do you not understand about recursions?

Comment: so currently i have, if(root == null){return ;} evaluate(root.left); evaluate(root.right); if(CharchtehrisDigit(root.data)){ return Integer.parseInt(root.data)} I don't know how to actually do the mathematical operations, I can pass return the root.data but I don't know how to compute it.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the code. In this form it is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry I just updated my comment, accidentally hit enter

Comment: Please update your question and add your code (in a proper format).